# Building height calculation from stereo Satellite images (Satellite Azimuth and Satellite Elevation)

Tags: photogrammetry

Can anybody help me in how to calculate building height from stereo satellite images sensor metadata (Mean satellite Azimuth and Mean Satellite Elevation)

Stereo Satellite  Images Azimuth's  (335.6616, 209.5149)
Stereo Satellite Images elevation   (83.8, 83.8)

I have applied some procedure to get multiplication factor with relative displacement but it is not working

First I calculated `1/tan(satele)* Sin(sataz)` & `1/tan(satele)* Cos(sataz)`

then vector addition to find multiplication factor

Answer (score 1):

If you know the date the image was taken, you can do the calculation based on the length of any objects shadow.

```
h = sin(vertical angle of sun)*length shadow/cos(vertical angle of sun)
```

The vertical angle can be taken e.g. from websites for solar power.

To be honest, this method is rather suited for small numbers of calculations and it is not your desired solution, but it works.

Comment: I wanted to use both left & right images for building height calculation with the help of sensor azimuth and elevation by measuring relative displacement of buildings in both image